# Entity Framework 6 Inheritance and Many to Many relationship in base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, many-to-many, table-per-type

I’m new to EF and can’t find a solution for my problem. I’m using Code first and have implemented some classes (about 15), which inheritance from a base class:

```
Class Base {
    …
}
Class A : Base {
    …
}
Class B : Base {
    .. 
}
```

The model is implemented as TPT. So there is a table “Base” and a table for every derived class like Table “A” and Table “B”. Derived classes contains only the fields which are not in the Base class... Now I would like to link every class with each other in form of many to many. So an object in class A or B can have many association with any object from class A or B. This works well with the following implementation:

```
Class Base {
    Public ICollection<Base> con1 {get; set;}
    Public ICollection<Base> con2 {get; set;}
}
```

My Problem is now the big overhead in a query. Every class has many fields so a query which includes con1 and con2 is joining every derived class (and contains every field of every class). But I need only the ID (Key) and the type of the derived class. Is there a best approach to solve this?

Another question is, if it is possible to have only one association-property in the Base class:

```
Class Base {
    Public ICollection<Base> associations {get; set;}
}
```

This association should contain all associations in both directions. Because my intention is not hierarchical like “Class B contains products” and “Class B belongs to Products” – it’s only an association between to objects without a significant meaning or direction like "Class B was also sold with Class A and...".

Thanks.

Jacek

Comment: "Every class has many fields so a query which includes con1 and con2 is joining every derived class (and contains every field of every class). But I need only the ID (Key) and the type of the derived class" - Show us your query please

Comment: My query is auto generated through EF from something like this:
Var productsb = ProductB in _context.ProductsB.Include(“con1”).include”con2)